Why AWS MSK throws KafkaJSProtocolError: Configuration is invalid when updating topic config?
I have AWS MSK setup with full admin permissions on it.
When I try to update topic configs I get the error mentioned in the title.
My code:
await admin.alterConfigs({
    validateOnly: false,
    resources: [{
      type: 2, //Corresponds to ConfigResourceTypes.TOPIC
      name: 'entity.agent',
      configEntries: [
        {
          name: 'cleanup.policy',
          value: 'compact'
        }
      ]
    }]
  })

Reading configs or lists of topics works fine. The topic exists.
Configs look just like in the docs:
https://kafka.js.org/docs/admin#alter-configs
Also, looks like Conduktor can do pretty much everything with these topics, except updating any config values...
I have no clue. Appreciate any help x
